# twitter's tweet button count does not count

Tags: php, twitter

I have a php generated wep page which has a lot of share buttons. Twitter, facebook and google+.

I have used the code that twitter gives for the tweet button, and it works fine.

You click it, the window pops up, you tweet.

My problem is, the count next to the button seems to be working normally throughout the site, except the photo gallery, which seems stuck at 0 even though I have tweeted it to test.

My page is [here](http://www.nightscene.gr/index.php?page=gallery&album=Villa%20Mercedes%20Patras%2021-01-12)

Is there some obvious error in it?

Also, are there any tools for detecting such errors for twitter like facebook has the OG debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly the problem is. I have faced with such issues in the past. May be an issue with twitter.

There are a few problems related to this.

If the link is shortened, Twitter won't add it up unless you add the "counturl" url property.

You may try adding these parameters in the tweet button code. This worked for me in one of my projects

```
data-url="http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button"
data-count="vertical"
data-counturl="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

Also another issue with twitter tweet button is that the tweet counts are not accurate in real time. They are cached and updated asynchronously. See http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button_faq#count-api-increment

Comment: Based on your experience, what would be a normal time that twitter needs to give the actual count? Should I know that what I changed failed after 1hour, 2hours, 1day?

Comment: I am not sure of that. I read it some where. I added that parameters in my tweet button and was working fine. Counts updated within minutes. I have reported issues with twitter. Sometimes it work sometimes it don't. :(